# How to display fragment tab activity?

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I have created 3 tabs, i.e. tab1, tab2 and tab3 using fragments.

When I click a button in tab1 it goes to another activity I.e., **songlist.Java and xml** files.

Again when I click a button in songlist then it should display tab2.

How can I display tab2 which is fragment tab in songlist which is normal activity?

Answer (score 0):

You should not call intent in tab1 tab2 and tab3 to display in the same activity. You need to use fragment for tab activity.If you need to display songlist in tab1 then you must extend Fragment in songlist.java and call songlist.java in tab1 Like in your MainActivity

```
   adapter.addFragment(new Songlist(),"tab1");
```

Then you will now able to switch the other tabs.

Comment: Now my songlist class extends to appCompatActivity If I extend songlist class with fragment then I cannot perform certain things like findViewById,toast etc

Comment: you can always call view.findViewById  or getActivity() as context.